# Spring boot security not authenticating when using @CrossOrigin

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have been struggeling with how to get spring security to work and allowing all origins to my REST-full application. I have looked up the problem and tried most suggestions but nothing seems to work independently they work fine but not together.

My controller is very simple since I am just doing some testing

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class TestController
{

    @RequestMapping(path="/test/{name}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(@PathVariable final String name)
    {
        return "Welcome " + name + "!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="/private/{name}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String privateTest(@PathVariable final String name)
    {
        return "Welcome private " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

My securityconfig looks like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        httpSecurity.cors().and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }
}
```

Does anybody have any suggestions? Also how do you normally create a secured restfull service when javascript is not allowed to do REST-full http request by default?

Answer (score 0):

```
.antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
// or anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
```

more about the ant match see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)